# Using JavaScript to submit a particular form button

Tags: javascript, web

As a college student at QANTM I regularly use its portal system to check information that is relevant to my study. However, the site uses a specific system that makes it impossible to view on small resolutions, such as mobile browsers.

I'm developing a small personal application that should allow me to view the contents of the site in my own formatted view. However, I'm having some issues executing JavaScript to submit credentials.

```
<form id="userslogin" method="post" action="javascript: saePortal.users.submitLogin();"     onsubmit="return false" class="x-hidden">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
<button type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" class="x-hidden" /></button>
</form>
```

This is basically the form structure of the portal and I am successfully able to alter the username and password field with my desired contents using

```
document.forms[0].username.value = 'text';
```

However I am unable to submit the results. I have done some searching online and it's not a simple matter of submitting the form. It refreshes the page.

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

I've also tried non-standard compliant code such as document.forms[0].submit.click(); and many variants of this, as well as using getElementById with no luck.

The site in question https://portal.qantm.com.au/. I'm unsure if this is a form of protection that's built into the site or if I'm simply using the wrong syntax.

Comment: I'm afraid it is much more complicated. You'll have to send POST requests manually to the required URLs, as AJAX is being used.

Comment: Why are setting attribute "onsubmit='return false'" to form tag? Its preventing the user to post data. instead need to give "onsubmit='return true'"

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript FormData-class if your browser supports it.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("username", username);
fd.append("password", password);
```

Then you could post this using jQuery or something.

```
$.ajax({
   url: portalurl,
   type: 'POST',
   data: fd,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change attribute `onsubmit="return true"` in form tag.